Early 1970's Movie Set In Italy
In about 1972 I saw a movie while in the Army in Alaska.  The film opened
with a red Corvette being off loaded from a ship.  The male star of the film was an American who had the car shipped to Italy and was standing on the dock
watching it being unloaded.  The song "Games People Play" by Joe South
was featured during the film. Can someone help me identify this movie?
It may have been an Italian film or not, I just don't know.

Could be "Come Together" from 1971 http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181398/

Ooh, I think I just watched this one. Hang on...

nope...different film. IMDB lists "ComeTogether" like @FranciscoV. says, so maybe that's it. Otherwise, add some more deets. Genre, memorable scenes, etc.

That;s the big problem, I can't remember anything else.  I think he met a girl and much of the movie was them driving around in that Corvette.

OK, I read a short synopisis on that " Come Together "

That might just be it !  It was weird and that's probably why I can't remember it.  But no word about the Corvette in the thing I read.  Thanks for working on this....  It is amazing you knew that.  Will advise

I just looked again and it's right there !   Games People Play is right in the

description !!!!!!  WOW, you did it, Francisco !!!!!!!

Francisco Got the answer in less than 24 hours !    This has been bugging me for 40 years !

@telement1 I am glad that I could help you, I posted an answer to your question.

Thanks again !  Did someone get killed in the end of the movie or what ?

The movie is Cometogether from 1971.

An American stuntman working on spaghetti westerns in Europe picks up two pretty American tourists and they decide to take a road trip around Europe together. However, things don't turn out exactly as each of them expected.

The soundtrack of the movie contains the song "Games People Play" by Joe South, you can see his Filmography here: Joe South - Filmography
Also listed here: Discogs - Various ‎– Cometogether (Original Soundtrack Recording)

I could not find a picture of the red Corvette, but here is a review with some pictures from the movie:
https://www.furiouscinema.com/come-together-1971-obscure-picks/


I wonder if the song " Games People Play " by Joe South was pirated on this movie.  It was a huge hit song right about that time and I always wondered why I couldn't find the movie by looking at the credits of the song....  know what I mean ?

How do I except answer ?

@telement1 there should be a checkmark on the left of the answer. You have to click on it

Will the check mark be next to your question ?  I see one but your Francisco is not there.

@telement1 Should be left to my answer

I am clicking it green but don't know how to send it or record it,
